# Concept about flatten use recursion with reduce and concat

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, reduce

Now I would like to flattening the array with multiple layers

From the other solution before and the developer's network, There is an effective solution:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3,4, [2,3,4]]];

function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
flattenDeep(arr1);// [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, there is a couple questions about the theory at that back that I want to ask: 
1. In my understanding, the function starts with initial value acc, and then it keeps looping all the element to see if it is an array or not.

In this case, the first 3 elements are 1,2,3 -- therefore is not an array and will be accumulated and returned as an array.

But start from the fourth element it returns

```
Array.isArray(arr1[3]) 
(5) [1, 2, 3, 4, Array(3)]
```

In this case, it triggers the condition acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)), which is a recursion of the function. How this condition helps to flatten the array?

And for the [] at the back, if my understand is right, it indicates the return form of the result from reduce should be an array?

Last but not least, any good reference for this topics that I should look for?

May thanks for your help!

**Further elaboration:**

let's say, now the val in the reduce function above is [1, 2, 3, 4,[[2,3,4]]].

In this first round of checking, the elements 1,2,3,4 are not array, but the last element still does, and it makes the whole argument still an array. For the next round of the recursion, would it just take the element [[2,3,4]]] and further evaluate the elements inside this array?

**Or with this example, what would be the first, second and third round outcome of the recursion process?**

Comment: > `But there is nth to indicate the reduction of the array.`

What do you mean by this, and what is the question here?

> `And for the [] at the back.`

This is a default value for reducer, i.e. `acc` the very first time will be equal to `[]` in your case.

Comment: I think you should read more about recursion.

Comment: @extempl May be my expression is not clear enough. What I mean is, in this function in the case in [1, 2, 3, 4, Array(3)], what would the recursion do so as to extract the value which under multiple layers?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I will take a look and many thanks =)

Comment: @PakHangLeung
> `what would the recursion do so as to extract the value which under multiple layers`

It looks like you think it will be called once. Why?

Well, as long as it is recursion, it will go to the latest non-array layer as deep as possible. I mean, when method calls itself inside it will call itself again and again, while condition (isArray) to make another recursive call is `true`.

Comment: @extempl Thanks and I guess I have an rough idea now =) 
But one question is, let's say, now the val in the reduce function above is [1, 2, 3, 4,[[2,3,4]]]. In this first round of checking, the elements 1,2,3,4 are not array, but the last element still does,  and it makes the whole argument still an array. 

For the next round of the recursion, would it just take the element [[2,3,4]]] and further evaluate the elements inside this array? 

Or with this example, what would be the first, second and third round outcome of the recursion process?

Many thanks again =)

Comment: @PakHangLeung Don't forget about `concat` that unwraps the arrays. `flattenDeep` will difenetly return an array, a flattened one, but `concat` will unwrap it an push its values to the `acc` array. So `flattenDeep([1,2,3,4,[[2,3,4]]])` -> ... -> `[1,2,3,4].concat(flattenDeep([[2,3,4]]))` -> `[1,2,3,4].concat([].concat(flattenDeep([2,3,4])))` -> ... -> `[1,2,3,4].concat([].concat([2,3,4]))` -> `[1,2,3,4].concat([2,3,4])` -> `[1,2,3,4,2,3,4]`. The `...` parts are where the non-array elements get pushed to the `acc` array which are self explanatory so no need to mention them.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Perfect and many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Second argument in the reduce method is the starting condition. If there is nothing provided, first `acc` will be the first array's element (see array.prototype.reduce on mdn).

I'm not sure about the `But there is nth to indicate the reduction of the array` statement. You're calling function recursively until you will find something that's not an array and then you're returning that value.

Look for js call stack, understand how js is stacking the functions, you can even draw it, it will help definitely because it's not easy case :)

Comment: I made an adjustment. Does it mean that, in an array like  [1, 2, 3, 4, Array(3)], it keeps looping through each layer of the nested array so as to find out the value which is not array?
Or how would the condition acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) works so as to get the value e.g in [[[[2,3,4]]]]?

Comment: As it is recursion it will call itself until some stop condition (here - when val !== array) is meet. So yes, it will be `looping` until it reach stop condition, then it will `go back` with respect to the call stack that was `accumulated`. I hope it helped at least a bit to understand the problem because recursion itself and js call stack are not so obvious :)